# jquery accordion - show all if https?

Tags: jquery, https, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Using jquery accordion and the https version of page needs to be secure, and with the accordion, a bunch of IE security warnings come up. Is there a way to show all/disable accordion if in https?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if you're in an HTTPS page like so:

```
var secure = (window.location.protocol === 'https:');
```